# URL Rewriting from a subdomain to main domain!

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am developing a pretty large website for a client, and its about 90% complete. It is currently hosted on a subdomain like so:

```
now:     v2.websitehere.com
when complete:     www.websitehere.com
```

My problem is that SO much of this site is linked to the temporary subdomain. The newsletter service, multiple google apis, etc. I also have multiple blogs installed that would be hard to move over. Literally, I have over 20 blogs hosted on the subdomain. I also have other PHP scripts that utilize SQL databases. So, what I am getting at is that a migration would be very difficult: time consuming, frustrating, and not something I want to do.

I am looking for a a good solution...similar to Wordpress's URL rewriting. Is there something I can do with .htaccess file? Any ideas would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the following to `.htaccess` in the parent directory above the directory of interest: `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /foo/bar/` or `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /bar/baz/`. Also see [How to get apache2 to redirect to a subdirectory](http://serverfault.com/q/9992/145545).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^v2\.websitehere\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.websitehere.com$1 [R,L]
```

Is what it should be.

Comment: I simply place this in the .htaccess file, and it works? What happens if I go to v2.yourwebsitehere.com. Will the URL display that, or will it redirect to www? Will it work both ways?

Comment: and will this work for all the sub-directories within v2.websitehere.com?

Comment: Yes it will redirect all subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^v2\.websitehere\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www\.websitehere\.com [L]
```

I have not tested this but it should give you an idea. this [link](http://blog.gwebtools.com/apache-htaccess-subdomain-redirect-rules/) may help you.

Comment: please see comments above/below...if ya know the answer. thanks :)

Comment: Didn't see them since I was the first to reply..
but it's now answered.